# MySQL Command-Line Script

Tags: mysql, command-line

These are the commands I need to execute in a script.  The date 2011.02.14 needs to be a parameter:

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword  
connect mydatabase  
source /var/www/2011.02.14.sql  
exit
```

How would I execute a script to do this?

Is the "mysql --user=myusername..." part of the script, or part of the command-line for executing the rest of the script?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your commands in a here doc

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword  << here_doc
connect mydatabase  
source /var/www/2011.02.14.sql  
exit
here_doc
```